# Equivalent of max() keep (partition by .. order by ..) in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

In an OBIEE report I want to have one line per agreement with the most recent status *as of a certain date* for that agreement.

One of the dimensions of the subject area is Agreement Status. In RPD they added a flag called Latest Flag so if I was interested in the *most recent* status of the agreement I could use that. However, I need the most recent status as of a date in the past (a month end), and cannot figure out how to do it.

If I have one row per status in the report I can show only the one that is most recent by :

```
case when "Dim - Agreement Status"."Agreement Status ID" = max("Dim - Agreement Status"."Agreement Status ID" by "Dim - Agreement Detail"."Agreement ID") then "Dim - Agreement Status"."Agreement Status" end
```

but wrapping that in a min or a max just gives a null.

In SQL I would write:

```
select agreement_id,max(agreement_status) keep (dense_rank last order by agreement_status_id) most recent_status
from agreement_status_table
where status_date < :some_date
group by agreement_id
```

but I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent in OBIEE.

Ultimately I need to use this in a filter, but am stuck on just displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

use evaluate_agg function and do it using the database engine.